# A view is missing as an ancestor of a view

Tags: swift, observable, swiftui, swift5, observableobject

I have a `login.swift` with mainly:

```
import SwiftUI

class GlobalEnvironment: ObservableObject {

    @Published var accountId: Int = 0
}

struct Login: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment

    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    @State var authenticationDdidFail: Bool = false
    @State var authenticationDidSucceed: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        if env.accountId == 0 {
            return AnyView(LoginView(username: self.$username, password: self.$password, authenticationDdidFail: self.$authenticationDdidFail, authenticationDidSucceed: self.$authenticationDidSucceed))
        } else {
            return AnyView(ContentView().environmentObject(GlobalEnvironment()))
        }


    }
}
...
```

The file sets the `env.accontId` after logging in, as well, successfully, within the LoginView.

Then I have a `data.swit` with:

```
struct Transaction: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var purpose: String
}

class Api {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment

    func getTransactions(completion: @escaping ([Transaction]) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://url.com/api.php?get_transactions&account=\(env.accountId)") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let transactions = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Transaction].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(transactions)
            }

        }
        .resume()

}
```

The API gets called from the `Transactions.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: GlobalEnvironment

    @State var transactions: [Transaction] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(transactions) { transaction in
                Text(transaction.purpose)

                }
            .environmentObject(GlobalEnvironment())
            .onAppear {
                Api().getTransactions { (transactions) in
                    self.transactions = transactions
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Transactions"))
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type GlobalEnvironment found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for GlobalEnvironment may be missing as an ancestor of this view.` for the `guard let url = URL(string: "https://url.com/api.php?get_transactions&account=\(env.accountId)") else { return }`.

From my understanding, adding the GlobalEnvironment to the Api class, it should work, but it doesn't. Instead, I already tried to add it within the function, but it doesn't work neither. Same for adding the .environmentObject() to the List View itself, as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to send your `environmentObject` on the call in `onAppear`

```
.onAppear 
{
    Api().getTransactions { (transactions) in
        self.transactions = transactions
    }.environmentObject(self.env)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be:

```
  .environmentObject(self.env)
```

Of course there could be further mistakes in SceneDelegate or somewhere else.

Comment: This does not have an effect

Comment: Despite my answer the approach you are going to present the views is not correct. The "if env.accountId == 0" should be in your ContentView and a LoginView a childview of it. In your approach it looks more like the other way arround.